# Get Page Type (Category/Tag) Using AJAX

Tags: ajax

I want to know if the opened page is a category/tag page. From the JavaScript file, I can pass only the permalink of the page. Is there a way I can find the page type?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is set a variable in the archive.php like `<script>var isArchive = true;</script>`. Or in any template do `if (is_archive()) { /* set the variable */ }`.

And then in the JS file do `if (typeof isArchive != 'undefined') { }` but there are probably way more elegant solutions that I'm unaware of.

This also probably assumes you load your scripts in the footer now that I think about it.

edit: of course you could also conditionally load your JS only on the archive pages and woudln't need to test anything in the javascript itself.

Comment: I am aware of both of these solutions, but neither of them are so elegant to use in a premium theme. I want do the check via AJAX. Reasons:

1. I don't want to output script tags unnecessarily in the code.

2. I want to have a single JS file.

Comment: Fair point, and I'm too interested in this if someone posts a decent solution :) Or how to check tag/category/post format what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could accomplish this is by using the [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function. The function is quite straightforward and lets you simply send anything from server side to your script.

This also outputs the variables inline, but this is the best WordPress allowd in this situation.